# nodejitsu 400 Error: ENOENT, open '/opt/run/snapshot/package/images/tmp/72118-89rld0.png

Tags: node.js, express, nodejitsu

I'm using nodejitsu to deploy a simple image upload program with express. In my code I've changed the default upload directory by following command

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({
        uploadDir: __dirname + "/images/tmp"
    }));
```

It's working fine on my localhost but when I'm using nodejitsu I'm getting this error

400 Error: ENOENT, open '/opt/run/snapshot/package/images/tmp/72118-89rld0.png.

Can anybody tell me how to make it work on nodejitsu as well? Actually I'm new to node as well as nodejitsu.

Comment: Actually I got a work around. I revert the upload directory back to default by                              app.use(express.bodyParser());                                    and then move the images to where I want them to store by using

    fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, callback);

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try to check directory at application start:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  upload = __dirname + "/images/tmp";

  fs.exists(upload, function (exist) {
    if (!exist) {
      fs.mkdir(upload);
    }
  });
```

It was helpful for me, may be it would helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that directory /opt/run/snapshot/package/images/tmp/ exists. Otherways just mkdir those directory

Answer (score -1):

At first check that the directory exist or not. If not then create it and follow the command

```
sudo jitsu deploy
```

I think the problem will be solved.